# Setting custom routes for error page using my header and footers

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

In the application folder there is an errors folder i was able to override the 404 page using a custom route like:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'my page'
```

but how about the other pages? how are they overridden? for example error_general i tried error_general_override and that didn't work. How can i set routes for these?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of CodeIgniter (and possibly subsequent versions), all of the views for errors are within the `/Application/Views/Errors` folder.

You would need to update these manually to use your header/footer.

The 404 override is generally used for CMS pages, so you can read the path, check the database to see if the page exists and if it does, show the page, otherwise show your own 404.

HTH